# A software to create multiple similar PDFs with a different name in each?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I'm looking to add to a PDF document with two pages, a paragraph with unique information. For a company declaration, you need to add the name and address of the person receiving that document.

The document is the same for 100 people, changing only that sentence, so the idea of creating 100 documents seems unlogical. Is there any software that does this?

I'm thinking of something like reading a CSV file and creating multiple PDFs with a different value on a specific field, but I can't find anything.

Comment: If the pdf is not too sophisticated, you can generate it automatically from a markdown file (for example with pandoc + latex->pdf). As the markdown file is a simple text file, it is easy to modify a name and a adress in it with a programme

Comment: I was looking to automate it without using code. A markdown file I would have manual work as well. But thanks for the suggestion.